# SPARQL-DL query with owl-api

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, owl-api

I'm writing an application using OWL-API and Hermit Reasoner. I would like to query data using SPARQL-DL by submitting query like:

```
PREFIX wine: <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#>
SELECT ?i
 WHERE { Type(?i, wine:PinotBlanc) }
 OR WHERE { Type(?i, wine:DryRedWine) }
```

Can I Do this directy with owl-api or should I use an external library (http://www.derivo.de/en/resources/sparql-dl-api/ ) ?  ( I need something like 
`queryEngine.query(my_query);`     )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in July 2013, the OWL-API does not support natively SPARQL-DL. You need to plug a third party library in order to make it work.

I am aware of two implementations (there's maybe more): One by Derivo (your link) and another one by [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/features/#cqa).

Comment: Yes, I found even OWL2QueryTab.

Answer (score 0):

I used OWL-API with Hermit and Pellet; both worked fine. The advantage of Pellet over Hermit is that it supports built-ins.

i.e. In Pellet, for some class `Teenager`, you can get seventeen year old persons using the following query:

```
Person and (hasAge value "17.0"^^double)
```

If you (or somebody) are still interested in, I can provide the Java class for it.

Answer (score 0):

A pure OWL-API-impl cannot provide non-workaround way to support SPARQL since it is not graph based solution. 
Now, starting v5, there is [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/wiki) which is jena-based OWL-API impl.

Comment: But is it possible to use reasoner while querying?

Comment: yes, why not? no difference with OWL-API-impl here.